# Android: Set Default soft keyboard

Tags: java, android

I have created a softkeyboard application. I would like to set it as my default soft keyboard while installing. Is it possible to add code in my softkeyboard application coding to set this keyboard as default keyboard while installing?

Comment: best you can do is launch the settings activity directly and let the user press the toggle button.

Comment: yes you can't perform this thing directly

Comment: a very good question, unfortunately Android says no to this one.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot set change the keyboard settings from your application. That would be a huge security risk.

Instead, do what most 3rd party keyboards do, bundle a small activity with your keyboard, where you tell the user how to change the keyboard settings, and also a button that takes the user to the correct settings page.

Comment: You know what is a huge security risk? Turning on your computer/smartphone. You should keep it off to be more secure. Seriously, Android has serious handicaps as it greatly limits application features invoking various unrelated reasons.

Comment: radhoo, you shouldn't neglect real security risks just because some seemingly harmless features can't be used without permission. There is a huge difference allowing an apk to change the soft keyboard compared to many other features. If changing the soft keyboard was allowed, some illwilling person could hide a trojan inside the simplest of applications, replacing the built-in keyboard with an identical keyboard containing a key logger. This article will help you understand why key loggers are dangerous: http://gamecreator.hubpages.com/hub/Why-Keyloggers-are-extremely-dangerous

Comment: Robert I used to do research in computer viruses years ago, so I am still familiar with various security risks. It ultimately comes to the training and self aware of the end user, to limit informational damage as there are endless ways of doing harm, and we cannot keep the smartphones tuned off just to be secure. Again I need to stress that the platform cannot imply such limitations. I think there is more damage done by unhappy users not knowing how to change a soft keyboard, and blaming the software - it happened to me  - than some rare and isolated cases were a  trojan/ worm would create.

Comment: radhoo, in that case we will just have to agree to disagree, because I do think a hidden install of a key logger could be far more damaging than a user not knowing how to switch keyboard. Helping the user can be done in many ways, I would like to point out Swiftkey as one prime example on how to do it.